# CoreData Multi-Threaded

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I’m having trouble with CoreData in a mulit-threaded environment.

I have a RestKit setup, meaning there is a persistentManagedObjectContext (private) of which I create a child-context (self.autoSyncMOC, also private). I’m not touching the mainManagedObjectContext of RestKit (main-thread), which is a child of the persistentMOC (sibling of my autoSyncMOC).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *autoSyncMOC;
```

This is the Code that throws the Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor exception:

```
self.autoSyncMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
self.autoSyncMOC = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;

[self.autoSyncMOC performBlockAndWait:^{

    //do normal fetch
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:...];
    fetchRequest.predicate =[NSPredicate...
    NSArray *result = [self.autoSyncMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    //do stuff with fetched objects (i.e. set a property) 
    for (DownloadableItem *item in result) {
        item.checksumDownload = @"test";
    }

    //save context       
    [self.autoSyncMOC save:...]; 
}];
```

What can go wrong here? I think I still don't understand the concepts.

I know that one needs more code and context to give a proper answer. I just want to know if my code is valid.

Thanks!

Comment: I just made another test that confuses me: when I save my context in a property, the code throws the exception. If I just create it within my method, everything works as expected. Can someone explain this?

Comment: What do you mean you save it to a property? Are you recreating it rather than storing it in a static property?

Comment: I save it in a static property.. created just once in a singleton class.

Comment: Are you accessing any properties from a main-thread (or other) NSManagedObject in this block, such as in creating your predicate or fetch request? How is autoSyncMOC created? Please show more of the code.

Comment: Just added some more code. I'm not accessing any NSManagedObject in my blocks.

Comment: Which line throws the exception, I assume the `save...` one? And you're passing in `nil` to the error parameters - if you pass in an error pointer, do you see any errors (I doubt it, but it's good to be sure!)

Comment: I do check for the errors - just left it out for simplicity. No errors.. The exception is thrown on the fetch request, however, if I leave out the for loop (i.e. don't touch any properties) then no exception is thrown.

Comment: I Just found an interesting forum thread about issues with the CoreData-assertions with iOS 8.4. Actually switching to iOS 9 does not throw the exception! https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug. Unfortunately, still unresolved: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19408